# How do I turn down play framework activator logging?

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, typesafe-activator

I recently upgraded my Play application to 2.3.4 and it's logging out quite a lot of debug messages from activator, including every resource file copied, the full compiler classpath etc.

I've tried setting

```
akka {
  loglevel="INFO"
}
```

in application.conf as suggested here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/SettingsLogger but this had no effect.

How do I turn off debug log messages?

Comment: As it says in the docs, `akka.loglevel` only affects logs from Akka, not the rest of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured this out. I was running

```
activator debug run
```

because in previous play versions

```
play debug run
```

would run with remote debugging on.

In activator this seems to turn on debug logging and

```
activator -jvm-debug run
```

runs with the remote debug port open.